# cut: option requires an argument -- 'f'

Tags: cut

I'm having trouble how to through this step for my homework. I insert the command:

```
tail -n +2 ../data/Pacifici2013_data.csv | cut -d ’;’ -f
```

and the output comes out saying that `cut: option requires an argument -- 'f'`

I have no idea how to proceed with this I'm following the book but it doesn't seem to help you out when you encounter this problem. How can I proceed?

Comment: If you're really using fancy quotes, i.e. `’;’`, then don't. It'll give you no end of troubles and unexpected errors in your code. You should be using straightforward ordinary quotes, i.e. `';'`.

Answer (score 3):

`-f` option of cut for sure requires something more.
Option `-f` is for "field".
You have to define which field you want cut to return.

For example :
`-f1` returns first field (separated by -d option => `;`)
`-f1-10` returns field 1 up to 10.
`-f1,5` returns field 1 and 5

See this real examples:

```
$ echo '1;q;w' |cut -d';' -f
cut: option requires an argument -- 'f'
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
$ echo '1;q;w' |cut -d';' -f2
q
$ echo '1;q;w' |cut -d';' -f2-3
q;w
$ echo '1;q;w' |cut -d';' -f1,3
1;w
```

PS: Also mind that `../data/Pacifici2013_data.csv`  refers to a csv file that is not in current directory but in a directory above (higher) than current.   For current directory you should use only one dot `./data/<...>` or just the filename directly. If file is in a completely different directory use full path.